# Как красиво вставлять php код в файл

Tags: php

Есть файлы, в которых идет html разметка и php код, сейчас они выглядят так:

```
<? if (...) { ?>
    <div>...</div>
<? }else{ ?>
    <span>...</span>
<? } >?
```

Или например:

```
<div>html code <?=$string;?> html <?=$num;?> code</div>
```

Не очень как-то... Как можно это все оформить по красивее? Какие есть варианты?

Comment: PSR-1,  PSR-2   зачем еще варианты ?
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Шаблонизаторы: [Twig, Blade, ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959751/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE-stylus-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-html/959756#959756)

Answer (score 1):

Принципиально более красивых вариантов нет. И не должно быть. В коде должна сохраняться гибкость и возможность выполнять определенные синтаксические конструкции.

Можно поменять на

```
{% if (...) %}
    <div>...</div>
{% else %}
    <span>...</span>
{% } %}
```

и

```
<div>html code {{ $string }} html {{ $num }} code</div>
```

но это следует делать не ради того чтобы стало "покрасивее" (что спорно), а потому что такой синтаксис будет поддерживаться шаблонизатором, предоставляющим много других полезных функций

Answer (score 0):

Шаблоны на PHP могут стать более читаемыми (красивыми) если использовать альтернативный синтаксис циклов и условных операоров.

```
<?php if (true): ?>
...
<?php endif ?>

<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <?= htmlspecialchars($item->name) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Обратите внимание, что можно опустить точку с запятой перед закрывающим дескриптором. Кроме того, шорттег `<?=` работает даже если шорттеги отключены.

Хочу ещё заметить, что читать шаблоны станет проще, если разбить их на небольшие компоненты. И готовить данные для шаблона заранее (исключить из кода шаблона бизнес-логику).

Смотрите как здорово:

```
/**
 * Подключение файла с буферизацией вывода
 * @param string $file
 * @param array $params
 * @return string
 */
function ob_include(): string
{
    extract(func_get_arg(1));
    ob_start();
    require func_get_arg(0);
    return ob_get_clean();
}

echo ob_include(__DIR__ . '/list.phtml', ['items' => $items]);
```

list.phtml:

```
Список редисок:
<ul>
    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
        <li><?= ob_include(__DIR__ . '/item.phtml', ['item' => $item]) ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<ul>
```

item.phtml:

```
<div>
    <?= htmlspecialchars($item->name) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: "читать будет легче" и "разбить на небольшие компоненты" - это взаимоисключающие параграфы. И в целом эта наколеночная поделка выглядит адовым костылем.

Comment: Почему же? Большие шаблоны используют много переменных, вложенных блоков -- легко запутаться. Мой пример только для демонстрации, но в реальной ситуации этот приём бывает очень полезен. Ну а "поделка" это просто базовые возможности PHP. Если проекту не нужна мощь шаблонизатора, то зачем усложнять?